# Only load ubuntu bootloader sometimes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup, bootloader, windows-10

I have a win10 and ubuntu 16.04 dual boot setup.  However I mostly use win10 and only use ubuntu for certain tasks.

**Is there anyway to suppress the ubuntu bootloader when starting up and only bring it up through activating windows boot options (like pressing F12)?**

This would be very helpful as it would save time the 9 times out of 10 that I just continue into windows.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to go to your BIOs settings at startup, the key needed changes from one pc to other, but it can be by holding down the ESC key, F2 or F9 (or those are at least the ones i have used in different machines). Once you are in your BIOs menu, go to the Boot option tab, there you should see something about Boot Order and a list of all installed OS you have, there just select Windows and press F5 or F6 to move it up and down, move it all the way up, above ubuntu, this way you are telling the computer to first try to boot Windows. 
That should do it i believe, good luck,

Comment: This worked perfectly!  You're a saint!

Comment: Glad it helped! :) if you could, please mark the question as answered, thank you c: